# how to call a stored procedure in codeigniter and show the output parameter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures, codeigniter-2

I have been using Stored procedures in codeigniter, but I can´t show the output parameter this is the message that show me the page

> Error Number: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SELECT @outputparam as Parameter3
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs******\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 331

This is how I call the procedure en codeigniter

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $success = $this->db->query("call insert_person(1,'$name','$email','$phone','$status',@outputparam)";
    $success->next_result();
    $success->free_result();
    $query = $this->db->query('select @outputparam as out_param');
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $query->row()->out_param;
```

I hope, you can help me.

Comment: Please tag which database you are using.

Comment: I'am using MySql sorry

Comment: There is no MySql sorry RDBMS available

Answer (score 0):

try to remove these lines and check,

```
$success->next_result();
$success->free_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, is because codeigniter doesn't have these lines of code in the config file "msqli_result.php"

```
function next_result(){
if (is_object($this->conn_id))
{
    return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);} }
```

with this you can use next-result() and free_result()